# Grails + BIRT Reporting - Casting and Passing Month and Year as Date to BIRT Report

Tags: mysql, date, grails, birt

I have integrated BIRT reporting into Grails and designed a report.
I have a parameter called startPeriod (Month and Year only) in my grails app and I want to pass that to BIRT. Then BIRT calls a stored procedure to generate the report.

Here is what I have:

**My GSP page**

```
<div class="fieldcontain">
    <label for="startPeriod">
       <g:message code="start.period" default="Start Period" />
    </label>

    <g:datePicker name="startPeriod" value="${startPeriod}" precision="month" noSelection="['':'-Choose-']" relativeYears="[-2..16]" />
</div>
```

My Stored Procedure (the one that BIRT calls)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_Report`(
    id LONG,
    startPeriod DATE
 )
BEGIN
-- my sql code
END
```

In my BIRT Report, I have a report parameter called startPeriod which is Linked To the SQL Parameter. I tried changing the data type of startPeriod of the report parameter to Date as well as String. But, The date is not being casted.

How do I cast the date "Tue Apr 01 00:00:00 EAT 2014" to "2014-04-01" (yyyy-mm-dd)?

Comment: Alternatively, you can pass the date in milliseconds and then, inside the SQL query of the DataSource-s of BIRT you can convert it to a date again.

Answer (score 0):

You have not chosen the easiest format to work with! You could directly send yyyy-mm-dd to the birt report from grails app. Otherwise put a script like this in the "*default value*" expression of the **dataset** parameter related to startDate (don't use *link to report parameter* option):

```
var parser=new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy", java.util.Locale.ENGLISH);
parser.parse(params["startPeriod"].value);
```

If localization is managed, you might have to replace *java.util.Locale.ENGLISH* with *reportContext.getLocale()*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tested it but it is still not casting it even if I changed the code to SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd"). Any other option?

Comment: Could you expand what you mean by "not casting": the code above casts the format you provided to a date object or throws an exception. The message of this exception would help, you could embed this cast in a try...catch block and post the exception message. You should also inspect the logs of BIRT engine, it might contain a warning related to this.

Comment: When I run java.lang.System.out.println("startPeriod:" + params["startPeriod"]); before casting, it is showing me that it is null. I have the correct params name. What does this mean? I guess since the g:datePicker only shows month and year, it is creating other variables such as startPeriod_month and startPeriod_year but it is passing a date like "Tue Apr 01 00:00:00 EAT 2014". Is it sufficient information?

Comment: Do I need to set the value after parsing such as params["startPeriod"].value = parser.parse(params["startPeriod"].value);

Comment: No, if the value is null it won't work. I assume this report parameter params["startPeriod"] is declared as "Date" datatype in the report: You should try to declare it as a "String" datatype instead, therefore this kind of value "Tue Apr 01 00:00:00 EAT 2014" should be correctly set, at least. Then, you will be able to parse it in the dataset parameter as mentionned in the answer. Let me know.